# Shell script to read log file from the last read line

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, sh

My requirement is to read a server log ( relatively large ) file which is being updated continuously, using a shell script from cron job. I will read until the last available line to find a string and email if string found. Next time when the cron job starts the job should read from the line or position where it was last finished. Any suggestions how can I do this in shell script.

Comment: You would have to save the file position to a temporary file, and start reading from that file position.

Answer (score 1):

the below could get you started :

```
tail -f your_file | while read line
do case "$line" in
        *"string_to_search"*) echo "" | mutt -s "Guilty string found" a_mail@mail.com       
;;
   esac
done
```

Comment: I would go with just grep `tail -f your_file | grep --line-buffered "string_to_search" | ... rest of the script`. However there is a problem with what op requested `Next time when the cron job starts the job should read from the line or position where it was last finished.`

Comment: @Kamil agreed, with a case statement though I think it's easier to integrate more strings to be searched for while taking the appropriate actions in each case (if different from case to case of course)

Answer (score 1):

I use `timeout` to timeout the `tail` and use some save file to save the line position we parsed:

```
# statefile where we save the number of parsed already lines
statefile=/tmp/statefile.txt

# initialize count variable - to zero, or from statefile
if [ -e "$statefile" ]; then
    count=$(<"$statefile")
else
    count=0
fi

# we timeout for 1 seconds outputting the lines
# the better timeout would be like 10 seconds for big file
# the `tail` command needs to jump `$count` lines inside the input file
timeout 1 tail -n +$count input_log_file |
# tee is used to pass the input to the updating part
tee >(
     # read number of parsed lines with `wc -l`
     # increment the count of parsed lines and save to statefile
     echo $(( count + $(wc -l) )) >"$statefile"
) |
# grep for the searched string
grep --line-buffered string_to_search |
# do the action if string_to_search is found
do_some_action_example_send_mail
```

Comment: `tail -n +10` on a file with 10 lines (already 10 the first time) will show line 10 that has been processed already.

Comment: Not a requirement, but please note: One day the log will be reset. The `tail` will be scanning thin air.

Comment: Then how should the script know if the log was reset? You need to provide a way to know that somehow.